# How to approximate timestamp

Tags: python, list, timestamp

I have a list of time stamps with milliseconds like `10:35:08.23562515422`. Now in the milliseconds, I want to have only first 3 values in the list like `10:35:08:235`. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is your timestamp a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> timestamps = ['10:35:08.23562515422', '10:35:08.24862517422', '10:35:08.31060347422', '10:35:15.00860347422']

>>> for time in timestamps:
...     dt = datetime.strptime(time[:-8], '%H:%M:%S.%f')
...     print datetime.strftime(dt, '%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]

10:35:08.235
10:35:08.248
10:35:08.310
10:35:15.008
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the hours, minutes and seconds will always be two digits each (which they should be), it's as easy as:

`timestamp = timestamp[:12]`